# Should I use JSONField or FileField to store JSON datas?

Tags: json, django, storage

I am wondering how I should store my JSON datas to have the best performances and scalability.

I have two options :

1. The first one would be to use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield), which will probably provides me an advantage in simplicity when it comes on performances and handling the datas since I don't have to get them out of a file each time.
2. My second option would be to store my JSON datas in FileFields as json files. This seems the best option since the huge quantity of JSON wouldn't be stored in a DataBase (only the location of the file). In my opinion it's the best option for scalability but maybe not for user performances since the file has to be read each time before displaying them in the template.

I would like to know if I am thinking reasonably, what's the best way between to store JSON datas for them to be reusable as fast as possible without making it complicated to the database & scalability ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json field will obviously has a good performance because of its indexing. A very good feature of it would be the native data access feature which means that you don't have to parse/load json and then query, you can just query directly from model field. Now since you have a huge json data it seems that file is a better option than model field but file only has advantage of storage. 
Quoting from some random article from google search:

> Postgres json field takes almost 11% extra data than the json file on your file system so test of 268mb file in json field is 233 mb (formatted json file)

Storing in a file has some cons which includes reading files parsing json and querying which is time consuming since it is disk based operations. Scalebility will not be a issue with json field although your db size will be high so moving the data might become tough for you.

So unless you have a shortage of database space you should choose jsonfield.